# Bike brakes and the parallel axis theorem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction, everyday-life, moment-of-inertia

In a bike, the best type of brake is the disc brake that brakes on disks close to the center of a wheel. The rim brake is worse and requires more power to stop the bike. By the parallel axis theorem:

$$I'=I+md^2. $$

So, as the distance increases from the center of the wheel, $I'$ increases. The moment of inertia increases. I believe this shows that the disc brake is better because the moment of inertia is less. It's higher for the rim brake. Am I right in my conclusion?

Comment: This would be news to bike manufacturers which advertise larger disc rotors as an upsell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is a disc attached to the rotating wheel one can argue that the moment of inertia of a wheel with a disc is (slightly) greater than a wheel used with rim brakes.
The difference might be lessened because the rims of the wheel used with rim brakes might be thicker.

*Am I right in my conclusion?* = No.

$\tau = I_{\rm axle} \alpha$ where $\tau$ is the braking torque, $I_{\rm axle}$ is the moment of inertia of the wheel about an axle and $\alpha$ the angular acceleration of the wheel.

The braking torque is equal to the distance $d$ the brake pads are from the axle  times the force $F$ exerted by the brake pads.
Assume that $I_{\rm axle,rim}\approx I_{\rm axle,disc}$.
Since $d_{\rm rim} > d_{\rm disc}$ then to produce the same angular acceleration $F_{\rm rim} < F_{\rm disc}$.

So the disc brake pads must produce a greater frictional force than the rim brake pads.

As to which type you use?
**Rim** brakes: are lighter; are easier to maintain; quick release wheels are the fastest/easiest to change; cost less; etc.
**Disc** brakes: offer greater stopping power; do not heat the rim, which potentially could cause tyre blowouts; allow for more precise braking making wheel lockup less likely; work better in wet weather and off-road; make it easier to use wider tires; damaged wheel rims will not ruin a ride; etc.

Answer (score 1):

no. the torque force required to slow down the bike wheel is the wheel radius times the friction force developed by the brake as it clamps the rim. a large radius rim brake will require a smaller friction force to develop the same braking torque as a small radius like a brake disc.

to stop a bike as effectively with a small disc brake as with a rim clamp ("caliper brake") requires the clamp force on the disc be really big. this is accomplished by hydraulically multiplying the brake handle force by using a large piston in the disc clamp and a small piston in the brake handle.